# Is ther a way to connect to TFS 2010 with silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Hi
Is there a way to connect to TFS using Silverlight?
I would like to create a dashboard with some information from my TFS (Workitems, build information etc).
The recommended way to connect to the TFS is via Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll (and the only supported way I guess).
But I can't use that dll in silverlight so my thought is to go the unsupported route by using the webservices directly.
Is that a bad idea?
I don't want to create a service in the middle I wan't to use the TFS directly. I have found very litte information about the TFS webservices.
What is the url for the webservices?
Cheers
/Jimmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working directly with the TFS Webservice is not impossible (for example, the Team Explorer Everywhere was developed like this), but it's a major effort. Because, as you have noticed already, there isn't much information around. The TEE guys had some support from Microsoft itself and where eventually bought up by Microsoft, so if your project isn't on about the same scale, I doubt that you will get much help.

The default address for the webservice if `http://<mytfsserver>:8080/tfs`

Answer (score 1):

I have been busy with something similar.  You can also achieve this by using WCF RIA Services.  In the WCF RIA Service you can then use a .NET library you create, in which you can use the TFS Api libraries (like Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll).

For information on WCF RIA Services, see http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/ to get you started.

Oops, I just read that you don't want to add a service layer.  But from experience I can say that doesn't cause that much extra work (if that is you worry).